# Having trouble understanding how to format HTML page using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I need to make my page look like this below minus the date at the top and flag but I dont understand how to make the boxes not stack like that and how to get the dropdowns to be beside each other. Any help appreciated I am learning.

What it is supposed to look like:

[image: What it is supposed to look like]

What mine Looks like:

[image: What Mine Looks like]

```css
fieldset {
    width: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: auto;
}

select {
    width: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>USA/EU Date and Time selector</title>
        <link href="date.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="main">
        <fieldset id="format">
            <legend>Format</legend>
            <label><input id="us" type="radio" name="format" value="US"/> US</label><br>
            <label><input id="eu" type="radio" name="format" value="European"/> European</label>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="fontSize">
            <legend>Font Size</legend>
            <label><input id="med" type="radio" name="fontSize" value="Medium"/> Medium</label><br>
            <label><input id="large" type="radio" name="fontSize" value="Large"/> Large</label><br>
            <label><input id="xLarge" type="radio" name="fontSize" value="X-Large"/> X-Large</label>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="flag">
            <legend>Flag</legend>
            <label><input id="show" type="checkbox" name="flag" value="Show"/> Show</label>
        </fieldset><br><br>

        <label for="colors">Text Color</label><br>
        <select name="colors" id="textColor">
            <option></option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="pink">Pink</option>
            <option value="purple">Purple</option>
            <option value="orange">Orange</option>
        </select>

        <label for="backgroundColor">Background Color</label>
        <select id="backgroundColor">
            <option></option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="purple">Purple</option>
            <option value="orange">Orange</option>
        </select><br>
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at Flex and Grid. They are very powerful and would definitely help you with making things align perfectly.

At the same time, your post is in a wrong section and should be put in HTML or CSS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a comment and not an answer. Provide working code if you want it to be considered an answer. And yes, I know you don't have enough rep to post comments, that's why you need to create a verifiable answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
         padding:8px;
         margin:auto;
         }
         #main{
         width:100%;              
         }
         .entry-container{
         margin:auto;align-items: center; 
         display:block; 
         width:100%;               
         text-align:center;
         }
         #format, #fontSize, #flag{                
         display:inline !important;
         padding-left:22px;
         padding-right:22px;          
         text-align:left !important;   
         min-width: 100px;      
         }
         #text-colors{
         display:flex;
         margin-top: 30px;
         }
         #text-colors .input-group{
         width:30%;
         display:grid;
         padding-left:12px;
         padding-right:12px;
         }
         #text-colors .input-group select{
         width:100%
         }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>USA/EU Date and Time selector</title>
      
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="main">
         <div class="entry-container">
            <fieldset id="format">
               <legend>Format</legend>
               <label><input id="us" type="radio" name="format" value="US"/> US</label><br>
               <label><input id="eu" type="radio" name="format" value="European"/> European</label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="fontSize">
               <legend>Font Size</legend>
               <label><input id="med" type="radio" name="fontSize" value="Medium"/> Medium</label><br>
               <label><input id="large" type="radio" name="fontSize" value="Large"/> Large</label><br>
               <label><input id="xLarge" type="radio" name="fontSize" value="X-Large"/> X-Large</label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="flag">
               <legend>Flag</legend>
               <label><input id="show" type="checkbox" name="flag" value="Show"/> Show</label>
            </fieldset>
         </div>
         <div id="text-colors">
            <div class="input-group">
               <label for="colors">Text Color</label><br>
               <select name="colors" id="textColor">
                  <option></option>
                  <option value="red">Red</option>
                  <option value="pink">Pink</option>
                  <option value="purple">Purple</option>
                  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
               <label for="backgroundColor">Background Color</label>
               <select id="backgroundColor">
                  <option></option>
                  <option value="red">Red</option>
                  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                  <option value="purple">Purple</option>
                  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
               <button id="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you much appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome.